# lodash - Find all objects by providing with two values to find within

Tags: javascript, json, object, lodash

I have an object containing product details with categories, colors, usage skills and price.
Now, I want to find all objects by providing min price and max price from my object:

```
const products = [{
      name: 'Product 1',
      usage: 'Home',
      skill: 'Easy',
      color: 'blue',
      price: 100.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 2',
      usage: 'Home',
      skill: 'Intermediate',
      color: 'red',
      price: 120.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 3',
      usage: 'Office',
      skill: 'Intermediate',
      color: 'green',
      price: 190.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 4',
      usage: 'Office',
      skill: 'Advanced',
      color: 'blue',
      price: 260.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 5',
      usage: 'Warehouse',
      skill: 'Advanced',
      color: 'white',
      price: 320.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 6',
      usage: 'Farm',
      skill: 'Intermediate',
      color: 'red',
      price: 120.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 7',
      usage: 'Space',
      skill: 'Advanced',
      color: 'green',
      price: 150.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 8',
      usage: 'Bathroom',
      skill: 'Easy',
      color: 'black',
      price: 9.00
    }];
```

Let say I provide minPrice = 100 and maxPrice = 190 so it should return me:

```
[{
  name: 'Product 1',
  usage: 'Home',
  skill: 'Easy',
  color: 'blue',
  price: 100.00
}, {
  name: 'Product 2',
  usage: 'Home',
  skill: 'Intermediate',
  color: 'red',
  price: 120.00
}, {
  name: 'Product 3',
  usage: 'Office',
  skill: 'Intermediate',
  color: 'green',
  price: 190.00
}, {
  name: 'Product 6',
  usage: 'Farm',
  skill: 'Intermediate',
  color: 'red',
  price: 120.00
}, {
  name: 'Product 7',
  usage: 'Space',
  skill: 'Advanced',
  color: 'green',
  price: 150.00
}]
```

Is there any predefined lodash function to get this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With lodash, you can use [_.fliter()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#filter) like that:

```
_.filter(products, function(p) {
  return p.price >= 100 && p.price <= 190;
});
```

It will return a new array that contains all matching occurrences. According to [the below example](https://jsfiddle.net/maximelafarie/kps08L5x/4/), you can store it in a variable and do whatever you want with it.

You can also wrap `_.filter()` inside a function:

```
function filterProduct(minPrice, maxPrice) {
  return _.filter(products, function(p) {
    return p.price >= minPrice && p.price <= maxPrice;
  });
}
```

Jsfiddle with your example here : https://jsfiddle.net/maximelafarie/kps08L5x/4/

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use `filter`

```
var minPrice = 100;
var maxPrice = 190;
var output = products.filter( s => s.price >= minPrice && s.price <= maxPrice );
```

**Demo**

```js
const products = [{
  name: 'Product 1',
  usage: 'Home',
  skill: 'Easy',
  color: 'blue',
  price: 100.00
}, {
  name: 'Product 2',
  usage: 'Home',
  skill: 'Intermediate',
  color: 'red',
  price: 120.00
}, {
  name: 'Product 3',
  usage: 'Office',
  skill: 'Intermediate',
  color: 'green',
  price: 190.00
}, {
  name: 'Product 4',
  usage: 'Office',
  skill: 'Advanced',
  color: 'blue',
  price: 260.00
}, {
  name: 'Product 5',
  usage: 'Warehouse',
  skill: 'Advanced',
  color: 'white',
  price: 320.00
}, {
  name: 'Product 6',
  usage: 'Farm',
  skill: 'Intermediate',
  color: 'red',
  price: 120.00
}, {
  name: 'Product 7',
  usage: 'Space',
  skill: 'Advanced',
  color: 'green',
  price: 150.00
}, {
  name: 'Product 8',
  usage: 'Bathroom',
  skill: 'Easy',
  color: 'black',
  price: 9.00
}];

var minPrice = 100;
var maxPrice = 190;
var output = products.filter(s => s.price >= minPrice && s.price <= maxPrice);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of array to get required result

**DEMO**

```js
const products = [{
      name: 'Product 1',
      usage: 'Home',
      skill: 'Easy',
      color: 'blue',
      price: 100.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 2',
      usage: 'Home',
      skill: 'Intermediate',
      color: 'red',
      price: 120.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 3',
      usage: 'Office',
      skill: 'Intermediate',
      color: 'green',
      price: 190.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 4',
      usage: 'Office',
      skill: 'Advanced',
      color: 'blue',
      price: 260.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 5',
      usage: 'Warehouse',
      skill: 'Advanced',
      color: 'white',
      price: 320.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 6',
      usage: 'Farm',
      skill: 'Intermediate',
      color: 'red',
      price: 120.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 7',
      usage: 'Space',
      skill: 'Advanced',
      color: 'green',
      price: 150.00
    }, {
      name: 'Product 8',
      usage: 'Bathroom',
      skill: 'Easy',
      color: 'black',
      price: 9.00
    }]

console.log(products.filter(({price})=>price>=100&&price<=190))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In point free fashion, this should do the trick:

```
import { filter, lte, gte, flow, get, overEvery } from 'lodash/fp'

const filterProduct =
  (min, max) => 
    filter(flow(
      get('price'),
      overEvery(gte(min), lte(max)),
    ))
```